# Limit datatable rows with just javascript, no Apex Controller

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, platform-event, lightning-components

I have a LWC Datatable that can return up to 200+ records so I want to initially limit the number of rows displayed down to 25. There is no apex controller involved so have not been able to successfully use the onloadmore event either. I am subscribing to a custom platform event channel which ends up returning all events, which leads me to limit number of rows once all events have been retrieved.

**Questions**

1. How can I limit the number of rows displayed within a data table without an Apex controller?
2. How can I enable a "load More" to display 25 more rows into the data table without an Apex controller?

**What I tried but didn't work**

**myLWC.js file**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import {
    subscribe,
    unsubscribe,
    onError,
    setDebugFlag,
    isEmpEnabled,
} from 'lightning/empApi';

export default class EmpApiLWC extends LightningElement {
    channelName = '/event/Test__e';
    myData;
    myColumns = { /* my column attributes */}

    subscription = {};

    // Initializes the component
    connectedCallback() {
        // ...
        // my connectedCallbackCode
        // ...
    }

    // Handles subscribe button click
    handleSubscribe() {
        // Callback invoked whenever a new event message is received
        const messageCallback = function (response) {
            console.log('New message received: ', JSON.stringify(response));
            // Response contains the payload of the new message received
            let responseItem = {
                createdDate: response.payload.createdDate,
                id: response.payload.unique_Id__c
                // other fields
            }

            this.myData = [ ...this.myData, responseItem ];

            /**
             * How do i limit to only display 25?
             * 
             */
        };

        // Invoke subscribe method of empApi. Pass reference to messageCallback
        subscribe(this.channelName, -1, messageCallback).then((response) => {
            // ...
            // my code
            this.subscription = response;
            // ...
        });
    }

    handleLoadMore(event) {
        // since this is a subscription to a custom platform event channel I cannot use this method
        // no apex controller
    }
}
```

**myLWC.html file**

```
    <template>
    <lightning-button
                variant="success"
                label="Subscribe"
                title="Subscribe"
                onclick={handleSubscribe}
                disabled={isSubscribeDisabled}
                class="slds-m-left_x-small"
            ></lightning-button>
    
    <lightning-datatable key="id"
                         data={myData}
                         columns={myColumns}
                         onloadmore={handleLoadMore}></lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). Arry.slice method can be used to chunk your data from starting to end position. with load more you can add 10 to your arrLimit or start from arrLimit + 1

```
let arrLimit = 25;
this.myData = [ ...this.myData, responseItem ].slice(0,arrLimit);
```